# Raster Editor in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, editing

I found two Raster Editors.

The first one is **[Serval Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Serval/)** and another one is  **Editor Raster** in SCP of QGIS. **Editor Raster** is working not well for me and **Serval** can edit only single pixel per time. However, I need to edit raster in a thousand of pixel.

So could you please recommend me some tool in QGIS that I can edit faster or kind of brush editor in QGIS?

Comment: You need more info to get and answer. Provide the raster format, the raster data type (integer, floating point etc), and exactly what values you want to change from what to what. I suspect you need a raster tool (like reclass) from you question but we need more info.

Comment: Thank you. The Raster I edit is land cover classification. Each pixel store value of each class. so I want to edit it pixel by pixel. but I cannot find other tools

Comment: but you said you want to do thousands at a time, I am sorry but what you are suggestings is not really how the most common raster structures work. Give us an example of an edit you wish to make and you will get more help, it still sounds like a reclass.

Comment: have the similar problem and I would try to use painting program like Gimp to edit the raster (e.g. geotiff) and re-do the georeferencing.